# How to allocate used serials to new entries in a document tracking system?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that contains the details for cheques received from our customers that get deposited as and when due. Currently, we follow a filing system where each cheque is assigned a number to track and retrieve which are serial. However, the serial are now running into 10,000 but I only have a few hundred cheques in possession.

How can I automate the numbering of the cheques that I receive to exclude the cheques that have been deposited / cleared based on a helper column that contains the status of the cheques as either "Cleared", "Uncleared" or "Deposited".

1. Column A - Date of Receipt
2. Column B - Customers Detials
3. Column C - Cheque Numeber
4. Column D - Cheque Date
5. Column E - Remarks
6. Column F - Status (all pending cheques are tagged "Uncleared", cheques out for collection are "Deposited" & cheques credited to the account "Cleared")
7. Column G - Filing number

I'm open to VBA scripts as well if I can automate it.

Comment: I still do not understand. The Cheque Number should be unique, what is your numbering for and where are the information the numbering depends on? Could you Show an example?

Comment: The cheque number is the number that is printed on the paper. Our unique filing number is in column G

Comment: @am2: Cheque numbers are not globally unique. You can get a globally unique number by combining RTN, account number, and check number-- which is probably way too long.

Comment: What you're saying is you want the filing number of a certain cheque to become available for use once that particular cheque is deposited/cleared?

Comment: Yes. But also add a new one if the current numbers are already taken. But I think that can be accommodated with an If statement.

Comment: Anyone who knows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the easiest solution is to take the MAX of the known filing numbers and add one.

So if you are entering these all into the same spreadsheet, and the spreadsheet has one header row, and the filing numbers are held in column G, you just need a formula like this in cell G3:

```
= MAX(G$2:G2) + 1
```

and then fill it down so the cells below are

```
= MAX(G$2:G3) + 1
= MAX(G$2:G4) + 1
= MAX(G$2:G5) + 1
= MAX(G$2:G6) + 1
```

so that it is taking the MAX of all the filing numbers immediately above and adds one.

Comment: I've tried that, but I need to also incorporate the criteria of Cheque status and keeping it stay put even when cheques from the previous lot get deposited.

Comment: I don't see why the status of a cheque matters, as long as it remains in the spreadsheet. Do you delete cheques from the spreadsheet when they clear?

Comment: No, the entire sheet is linked to the receivables & Bank. We do not delete the data columns.

The status column matters for me in this purpose because, I want the numbering to take the status of the cheque into account and then issue the next serial number after it looks though the cheques cleared

Comment: That would mean that one of the cheques in your list could have the same filing number as a cheque that has previously cleared. Is that intentional? Seems to me you'd want to keep the same filing number forever, for recordkeeping purposes.

Comment: Actually the purpose of this excercise is to keep filing simple as currently, for storage, we need to maintain and track large number of filing numbers which were previously allotted to cheques, but currently they're empty due to cheques being cleared. Think of it as a large filing cabinet that contains numbered sections for storage. The items coming in do not need to be stored in a new section, but just be allotted the old one that currently is not occupied.

Here's a example file:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AspBcLz3_XI6jJh9TUeNQDubvi6dGA

Comment: I still do not understand. To find a solution for your example it is enough to write E2: 1, E3: =E2+1 and copy from E3 down to the end. But I do not think this is what you need. Is there another example, one, where is to be seen, in which case the numbers have to be identical?

Comment: Funny I didn't receive a notification for this reply. What do you need exactly ?

Comment: Anyone who can atleast share how I can go about achieving this ?

Comment: How can I bump this to the top for answers and get more attention ?